# Visual Studio Reordering RC Files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resources

I'm fairly sure I'm not imagining this, but it seems to me that Visual Studio (2010) often takes it upon itself to change the order of things in my source-controlled RC files.

For example, I might add some strings to the string table, or edit a dialog. Then, when I do a comparison for source-control purposes, I find whole sections of the string table, or whole dialog definitions, have been moved about, making merges and such like a much bigger pain than they need to be.

**Am I imagining this?**

**If not, is there any way to stop it happening?**